Difference between WebSocket Proxy Server implementations
I have been exploring different ways we could proxy WebSocket data. I came across this implementation.
Option 1:
func (proxy *ProxyHttpServer) serveWebsocket(ctx *ProxyCtx, w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    targetURL := url.URL{Scheme: "ws", Host: req.URL.Host, Path: req.URL.Path}

    targetConn, err := proxy.connectDial(ctx, "tcp", targetURL.Host)
    if err != nil {
        ctx.Warnf("Error dialing target site: %v", err)
        return
    }
    defer targetConn.Close()

    // Connect to Client
    hj, ok := w.(http.Hijacker)
    if !ok {
        panic("httpserver does not support hijacking")
    }
    clientConn, _, err := hj.Hijack()
    if err != nil {
        ctx.Warnf("Hijack error: %v", err)
        return
    }

    // Perform handshake
    if err := proxy.websocketHandshake(ctx, req, targetConn, clientConn); err != nil {
        ctx.Warnf("Websocket handshake error: %v", err)
        return
    }

    // Proxy ws connection
    proxy.proxyWebsocket(ctx, targetConn, clientConn)
}

func (proxy *ProxyHttpServer) websocketHandshake(ctx *ProxyCtx, req *http.Request, targetSiteConn io.ReadWriter, clientConn io.ReadWriter) error {
    // write handshake request to target
    err := req.Write(targetSiteConn)
    if err != nil {
        ctx.Warnf("Error writing upgrade request: %v", err)
        return err
    }

    targetTLSReader := bufio.NewReader(targetSiteConn)

    // Read handshake response from target
    resp, err := http.ReadResponse(targetTLSReader, req)
    if err != nil {
        ctx.Warnf("Error reading handhsake response  %v", err)
        return err
    }

    // Run response through handlers
    resp = proxy.filterResponse(resp, ctx)

    // Proxy handshake back to client
    err = resp.Write(clientConn)
    if err != nil {
        ctx.Warnf("Error writing handshake response: %v", err)
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func (proxy *ProxyHttpServer) proxyWebsocket(ctx *ProxyCtx, dest io.ReadWriter, source io.ReadWriter) {
    errChan := make(chan error, 2)
    cp := func(dst io.Writer, src io.Reader) {
        _, err := io.Copy(dst, src)
        ctx.Warnf("Websocket error: %v", err)
        errChan <- err
    }

    // Start proxying websocket data
    go cp(dest, source)
    go cp(source, dest)
    <-errChan
}


This is a little bit different from the implementation that I came up with:
Option 2: My implementaion
...
import "nhooyr.io/websocket"
...

func handleWebSocketConnection(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    connA, err := websocket.Accept(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to accept WebSocket connection: %v", err)
        return
    }
    defer connA.Close(200, "Closing connectionA")

    // Connect to dest server
    caCert, _ := os.ReadFile(caCertPath)
    caPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    if !caPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCert) {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to append CA certificate")
    }
    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
        RootCAs: caPool,
    }
    httpClient := &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            TLSClientConfig: tlsConfig,
        },
    }
    connB, _, err := websocket.Dial(r.Context(), AggWsAddr, &websocket.DialOptions{
        HTTPClient: httpClient,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to connect: %v", err)
        return
    }
    defer connB.Close(200, "Closing connection")

    // Start goroutines to forward messages between client and agg
    go forwardMessages(connA, connB, "Conn A -> Conn B")
    go forwardMessages(connB, connA, "Conn B -> Conn A")

    // Keep the connection open indefinitely
    select {}
}

I was just curious to understand why one would choose one implementation over the other.
A few differences I see are:

The first implementation is library-agnostic, but my implementation (the second one) specifically uses https://pkg.go.dev/nhooyr.io/websocket. Also, in the second implementation, the library takes care of the WebSocket handshake, whereas in the first implementation, it is handled by the proxy itself.
More importantly, my implementation will make two WebSocket connections: client <-> proxy and proxy <-> server. So, I need to take care of copying headers from the proxy that are meant for the destination server. On the other hand, in the first implementation, there is a single WebSocket handshake between the client and the server. The proxy is forwarding those messages as well. So, I guess we don't have to worry about copying headers to the destination server.

Thanks!
